# Storing the events of a pokerhand in a data base

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a program in C++ that analyze poker hands. I would like yo use SQL to store data about hands, players and sessions.

I have a pretty good ide about what I would like to store in my session and player table, but the hand table is a bit more tricky.

A single hand needs to contain the name of all the players, their hands (if shown), their stacks, the date, the stakes and so on. The problem is with saving the events. A single 6-player hand could be as simple as fold-fold-fold-fold-raise,4$-fold, but it could potentially be MUCH longer.

The only way I can think of doing this is having a column called "Events" and storing the action a string, "F-F-F-F-R,4-F".

There must me a better, more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem like a problem you would want to store in a relational database, but rather perhaps a NoSQL database.

Comment: Cool Question!! - My first thought (and I'm going to think about it more) is that since there are only 3 options: `Fold` / `Call` / `Raise` and `Fold` is the most common - Make Fold = `NULL` to save space, set Call = `0` and Raise = $$ amount... Again, first thought about space-saving

Comment: Next thought - since there is a max of 9 per table, maybe have 9 fields - one for each player - and in another field state who the dealer is...

Comment: Is storage really that expensive that one need to *save space* in this manner?

Comment: @eggyal I'm not sure, I have barely played around with SQL. The maximum number of "actions" a single hand can have in a 9-handed game where everyone has 100 big blinds, would be something like 450 (although it is unlikely this would ever happen). Could a single column store 450 x ~7 chars? What about when you have played thousands of hands?

Comment: @MikeBrant Cool, I'll read up on NoSQL. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnBustos You also have re-raise :) Cool thoughts though!

Comment: @Magnus, I thought about that - If you have a separate `bets` table, you could still associate the bets with each hand and store them as separate rows. As for re-raise, it's the same as raise in terms of all you need to do is store the $$ amount. If two people have a dollar amount in a single round of betting, you know it to be a re-raise.

Answer (score 3):

Storing a *sequence* of events in a single row is a violation of first normal form, and considered bad practice.

So instead of storing the whole sequence of events in a single row for the hand, you should have a sequence of rows in another table (John Bustos suggested “bets”, but your suggested column name ”Events” might make a good table name as well) associated with it. Every event would contain the identifier of the hand it belongs to, a sequence number to order events. These two columns would form the primary key of that table. Then you can have a column to store the kind of event (an `ENUM` might proove useful for this) and for some events additional data like an amount.

To list all events in a query, you can either generate multiple rows, one for each event. Or you have a subquery which turns all of these rows into text, which you can then aggregate into a single string using `GROUP_CONCAT`.